# Puppeteer intercepted click

Tags: javascript, typescript, puppeteer

i crawl webpage fully written in javascript.

My problem: Many button when are loaded dont't have overlay. Within 10 ms overlay (loader) appear. After that overlay dismiss. I used selenium before and I catch ElementClickInterceptedException. When this exception was fired I repeat click.

Any idea how achive this with puppeteer. I can't use waitFor or another delay. Page must be fast as possible.

P.S. I used typescript

Thanks for your help

//EDIT

I try many workarounds. Last state:

```ts
let timeOut = 30000;
await page.waitForSelector(cssSelector, { visible: true, timeout: timeOut });
while (timeOut > 0) {
  try {
    await page.click(cssSelector);
    return;
  } catch (e) {
    await page.waitFor(100);
    timeOut -= 100;
  }
}
```

Click is fired before overlay appear.

Comment: Assume no one knows what your code looks like. Can you post *some* source code?

Comment: First post edited